# Vue template won't render if array in data function is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm having a problem with a Vue template where no elements on the page will not render unless an array declared on `data` is already populated.

The problem is that the `data` is only populated after an API call made by submitting a form.

The browser console reads `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"`

If I comment out the `{{classes.data.response}}` the form displays but will not otherwise.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
<template>
  <div class="container"> 
        <form @submit="getClass">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." v-model="class_id">
          <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div v-if="classes"> <!-- conditionally render if array has results -->
         {{classes.data.response}} <!-- form shows when this is commented out -->
        </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The data block

```
 data() {
    return {
      classes: []
    };
  },
...
```

And the methods block

```
methods: {

...
     // Request
      axios(config)
        .then(response => (this.classes = response))
   
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('There was an error :' , error);
        });
      }
}
```

I'm relatively new to Vue so if anyone can tell me what is going wrong here I'd much appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it should `this.classes = response.data.response`

Comment: Hey @mikeym please take a look at my answer and let me know if it helped you or if there is still anything unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### this.classes.data.response is not defined

You can try to be more specific when assigning the response to `classes`. Instead of `this.classes = response`, do this `this.classes = response.data.response`. `response.data.response` is the Array you are looking for, not `response`.

```js
methods: {

...
   // Request
      axios(config)
        .then(response => (this.classes = response.data.response))
   
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('There was an error :' , error);
        });
      }
}
```

Then in the template just write `{{ classes }}` instead of `{{ classes.data.response }}`, also `v-if="classes.length > 0"` instead of just `v-if="classes"`.

`v-if="classes"` will always be `true`

`v-if="classes.length > 0"` will be `true` when the Array has more the 0 elements in it

### Why

Because of the asynchronous nature of the API request, the moment the form tries to render `this.classes` will still be the empty Array you defined. Only later, once the API request has finished, `this.classes` will have the data it needs.

Answer (score 0):

empty arrays are truthy, so `v-if="classes"` will always be true. use `classes.length`, as an empty array will result in `0` which is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

maybe yo can do something like

```
    <div v-if="classes.length>0">
     {{classes.data.response}} 
    </div>
```